# Why are my links to my site disappearing from feeds after 2-3 hours?

Tags: sharing, facebook-stream-story

I have a web site that gets quite a bit of traffic from Facebook. I've never had any problems sharing links to it on my Facebook page, but starting this afternoon, whenever I post a link to my web site from my facebook page, the post disappears from all users' feeds after 2-3 hours. This has happened 3 times now and I can't understand why. At first I thought it was my page itself, but it seems to be my domain because when I share from a different page (the same domain), it also disappears.

It worked fine this morning but not now. What is going on? Is this a glitch or is it some kind of system FB has in place now? This is really hurting traffic and clicks out from FB to my site.

Thank you.

Edit: looking back, it seems this may have started happening around Tuesday. Is there some kind of system in place now to limit the amount of clicks out you can get from a post? I can't see any other reason it's happening...

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible causes:

1. Links that you use is a dynamic link which at times can be changed, use the static link. Example your link like this: `http://www.domain.com/page.php?var=xxxxxxxx`, where the parameter xxxxxxxx values ​​on the links can change at any time may be due to activity updates. This will cause facebook can not find a link that has been logged.
2. Bandwidth & server connection you less stable.

If I may suggest, avoid links / URLs dynamically & use the SEO Friendly link/URL like this page URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529022/why-are-my-links-to-my-site-disappearing-from-feeds-after-2-3-hours`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. My URLs can never change and are totally SEO friendly. I've never had this problem and have been using Facebook for a long time. And I'm on a very stable server and have guys monitoring bandwidth and downtime constantly. In looking back at posts, this is definitely something that started exactly Tuesday. Is there anyone from FB here who can chime in on this? did something get implemented recently that would eliminate posts from feeds if X happens? This problem only seems to occur on links out, not regular status updates.

Comment: Mmm.. apparently not the cause of your website, but from the FB. There may be a bug in the coding / system they are. I have not check my FB page like, we'll see what the next few days are still often disappear. If still disappear, you should complain to the FB. Hehehe ..

Comment: Yeah I've been looking at other Pages and seeing if theirs are falling out of feeds too. I've seen some possible evidence of it, but nothing like mine. I'm just hoping to hear what's going on soon! Thanks for your responses :)